# How to use Javascript time()?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code to show a calender for today using the `date.gettime` method evaluate the time. The `refreshtime()` function makes the time dynamic, but it is not working. Why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function refreshtime() {
       var timeis=gettime()
       document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=timeis
   }

   function gettime() {
       var time=new Date()
       var hour=time.getHours()
       if(hour<12)
           var ampm="am"
       else
           ampm="pm"
       var minute=time.getMinutes()
       var seconds=time.getSeconds()
       var text=hour+':'+ minute+':'+seconds+ampm
       return text
   }
   function nameofmonth(month) {  
       var monthname=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
       return monthname[month]
   }  
   function monthdays(month,year) {
       var daysofmonth=new Array(31,28,31,31,30,31,31,31,30,31,30,31)
       if(year%4==0)
           daysofmonth[1]=29  
       return daysofmonth[month]   
   }
   function table() {
       var now=new Date()
       var hour=now.getHours()
       var minute=now.getMinutes()
       var second=now.getSeconds()
       var date=now.getDate()
       var month=now.getMonth() 
       var year=now.getFullYear()
       now.setFullYear(year,month,1)
       var firstday=now.getDay()
       var monthname=nameofmonth(month)
       var daysofmonth=monthdays(month,year)
       if(firstday>0)
           var k=-(firstday-1)
       else
           k=1
       var table="<table border=5 cellspacing=9 cellpadding=17>"
       table +="<th colspan=7>"+monthname+" "+date+"th</th>"
       table +="<tr><th>sun</th><th>mon</th><th>tue</><th>wed</th><th>thu</th><th>fri</><th>sat</th></tr>"
       for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
           table+="<tr>"
           for(var j=0;j<7;j++) {
               if(k<=daysofmonth && k>0) {
                   if(k==date)
                       table+='<td id="clock" bgcolor="aqua">'+k+'<br>'+gettime()+ '</td>'
                   else
                       table+='<td>'+k+'</td>'
                   k=parseInt(k)
               }
               else
                   table+="<td></td>"
               k++
           }
           table+="</tr>"
       }
       table+="</table>"
       document.write(table)
   }      
 </script> 
 </head>
 <body onload="table();setInterval('refreshtime()',1000)")
 </body >
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow sovon. I did some rework to your question to make it a little clearer, let me know if I messed it up. You should run your code through [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it'll help you clean it up some.

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine. Looks good in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVvXs/

If you are testing in IE you should add a tbody tag to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your `table()` -function clears the present document and overrides all the original HTML and all it's contents. Only what is left in the new document is the HTML created by `table()`.

You should use `document.write()`-method from a different frame, or create the whole HTML-document by fly.